# Bug with highcharts pie-basic percent

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using the code of demo pie-basic ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/)) with the following values :

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
        ['Firefox',   34],
        ['IE',       33],         
        ['Safari',    26],
        ['Opera',     7],
    ]
}]
```

and the problem is that it appears as `7.000000000000001%` instead of `7%`.

How can I get a rounded value to appear?

[image]

Comment: must be some error in data : check in http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

Comment: That's weird, I don't see any issue with it, it apepars as 7% for me.

Comment: this is the same code of the demo, juste the 4 values changes. Im with Firefox browser

Comment: I don't see any issue with in my firefox browser

Comment: Yes, there is definitely a problem here. I can reproduce this in at least Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can't tell you how to prevent the floating point error from occurring in the first place, but I can tell you how to hide it from the user.

You can simply use `Math.round()` in your `formatter` function, as follows:

```
formatter: function() {
    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
}
```

You already have a formatter function; I've just added `Math.round()` to it.

I've updated your fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/A2cVe/1/

**[EDIT]** You mention that the tooltip was also showing the error. There is also a separate `formatter` function for that. I've updated the fiddle again with both formatter functions now edited to show the expected value: http://jsfiddle.net/A2cVe/2/

Comment: It's ok but when the mouse is over, the percent in popup is not good

Comment: yes its good with the ling below and this : tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
     return this.point.name + '<br/>' + this.series.name + ": <b>" + Math.round(this.percentage) + "%</b>";
    }
   },

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related with known bug https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/897